# Подскажите пожалуйста почему не запускается измененный JS файл в ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

У меня есть JS файл asd.js

Не запускается измененный скрипт, вместо этого запускается старый.

Comment: Кэш браузера. Кэш на сервере. Все что угодно. Попробуйте дописать ?v=123 к url файла - если поможет - значит точно кэш :)

Answer (score 0):

Если в вашем проекте используется механизм mvc area, то все скачиваемые файлы (js. css и т.д.) из "дочерних" проектов не будут копироваться в папку-мастер, откуда и происходит скачивание клиенту. В моей практике приходилось использовать bat-файл для переноса изменений.